# Kafka Connect with Redis - Sink never work

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to setup the data flow as:

- Source: PostgreSQL, using `io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector`
- Sink: Redis, using `com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector`

Here is my `docker-compose` to start services.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  content_sql:
    container_name: content_sql
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: content_admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456xyz
      POSTGRES_DB: madison_content
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "wal_level=logical"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always

  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:7-alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: zookeeper:3.8-temurin
    environment:
      JVMFLAGS: -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
    restart: always

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: ubuntu/kafka:edge
    environment:
      TZ: UTC
      ZOOKEEPER_HOST: host.docker.internal
      ZOOKEEPER_PORT: 2181
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    restart: always

  kafka_connector:
    container_name: kafka_connector
    image: debezium/connect-base:latest
    environment:
      GROUP_ID: 1
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: content_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: cache_content
      STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_statuses
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR: /usr/share/local-connectors
    volumes:
      - ~/Documents/kafka-plugins:/usr/share/local-connectors
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
      - content_sql
      - kafka
      - redis
      - zookeeper
    restart: always
```

The `docker-compose` can start successfully and plugins are loaded correctly.

Here is my REST request to register the connector.

PostgreSQL Source

```
{
    "name": "postgres-source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "task.max": "3",
        "database.hostname": "content_sql",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "content_admin",
        "database.password": "123456xyz",
        "database.dbname": "madison_content",
        "database.whitelist": "madison_content",
        "table.include.list": "public.thread",
        "topic.prefix": "cache",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput"
    }
}
```

Redis Sink

```
{
    "name": "redis-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.redis.RedisSinkConnector",
        "redis.hosts": "redis:6379",
        "redis.database": "1",
        "redis.client.mode": "Standalone",
        "task.max": "3",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "plugin.path": "/usr/share/local-connectors",
        "topics.regex": "cache.(.*)"
    }
}
```

When I inserted data to PostgreSQL, I noticed that INFO log showed "N records ..." , I also double-checked manually the Kafka topic and message. The topic was created successfully, message was there. But somehow, the sink never work.

I checked the Redis data by using `redis-cli` with command `KEYS *`. Is it the correct way?

May you please help to have a look? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the Connect server logs? Status endpoint of the sink connector? What does the data in your topic look like?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I check the status of both source and sink. They are "RUNNING". I used StringConverter. The data in my Redis looks like this "1) "__kafka.offset.cache_content.3"
2) "[\"postgres-source\",{\"server\":\"cache\"}]""

Comment: I solved it. I think it is because of something wrong while I put the configuration to postgresql. I changed the image to `debezium/postgres` and it works.

Comment: You said that the Debezium connector worked fine, so that image shouldn't matter for the Redis sink

Comment: Let's me double-check by reverting the image to standard image from PostgreSQL. Maybe I mis-configured somewhere.